# Find all value minor of 2 ( php foreach loop )

Tags: php, foreach

I have made a PHP foreach loop for my array and I have a question:

I can show only the data less than 2 executed by the calculation? Is possible?

```
foreach (array_combine($fattorerov, $fattorenorm) as $valore => $valore2) {
    $conteggio = $valore2." X ".$valore." = ".$valore * (0.70);
    echo $conteggio."<br><br>";  
}
```

Comment: If I understand it right a simple if statement would do it?!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put if statment in your loop -:

```
If($conteggio<2){
echo $conteggio;
}
```